# Need help on this tooling api code .Its returning me 0 results

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

Just need help why is it returning 0 results.

```
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId+FROM+UserFieldAccess+WHERE+DurableId+=\''+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(string.valueOf(Account.Industry), 'UTF-8')+'\'');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');        
req.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
system.debug('full response '+res.getbody());
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by running the query in Workbench's REST explorer to check that you query is valid and that there are actual results.

Then, URL encode your entire query and not just your parameter value. Single quotes aren't supposed to be in URL.

Comment: Actually in Query editor i tried running this query,its giving me 0 result again,   SELECT EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId FROM UserFieldAccess WHERE UserId='0057F000000gHe6' AND EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Account' AND DurableId='Account.Industry'

Comment: in workbench the above query is giving 0 results . /services/data/v47.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId+FROM+UserFieldAccess+WHERE+UserId='0057F000000gHe6'+AND+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Account'+AND+DurableId='Account.Industry'

Comment: This means that you first need to fix your query before calling it from Apex. I suggest that you create a new question for this.